# swiftui: How to catch onWillDisappear

Tags: swiftui, lifecycle

I have google's YTPlayerView leveraged wrapped in UIViewRepresentable in a swiftui project. When user leaves the view with YTPlayerView in progress audio keeps playing
in the background. So I need to call stopVideo() on YTPlayerView wrapped instance when this happens.
Given that UIViewRepresentable has no view lifecycle management callbacks that
I know of I hooked up onDisappear in the View utilizing YTPlayerView as its child.
However I get

> Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This
> will create a new instance each time.

Cause stopVideo is called after the view is already gone.
Is there an equivalent of UIKit viewWillDisappear to make the call then the view is still onscreen? ("installed on a View" in SwiftUI newspeak that is)

The ugliness:

```
struct YTPlayer: UIViewRepresentable, Stoppable {
    internal init(observer: YTPlayerViewDelegateObserverProxy, videoID: String, model: PlayerViewModel) {
        self.observer = observer
        self.videoID = videoID
        self._model = StateObject(wrappedValue: model)
        model.ytplayer = self
    }
    
    @State var observer: YTPlayerViewDelegateObserverProxy
    let videoID: String
    static var cache = NSCache<NSString, YTPlayerView>()
    @StateObject private var model: PlayerViewModel
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> YTPlayerView {
        if let pv = YTPlayer.cache.object(forKey: videoID as NSString) {
            return pv
        }
        let view = YTPlayerView()
        YTPlayer.cache.setObject(view, forKey: videoID as NSString)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ player: YTPlayerView, context: Context) {
        guard player.delegate !== observer else {
            return
        }
        model.ytplayerview = player
        let playerVars = ["playsinline" : NSNumber(1)]
        player.delegate = observer
        player.load(withVideoId: videoID, playerVars: playerVars)
    }
    
    static func dismantleUIView(player: YTPlayerView, coordinator: Self.Coordinator)
    {
        player.stopVideo()
    }
    
    func stop() {
        guard let player = model.ytplayerview as? YTPlayerView else {
            assertionFailure()
            return
        }
        player.stopVideo()
    }
    func anyview() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(self)
    }
}
```

[image]

Even more ugliness:

```
final public class PlayerViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
...
    public var ytplayerview: UIView?
    public var ytplayer: Stoppable?



public protocol Stoppable
{
    func stop()
    // I know, pathetic, I moved it to the Lincoln street...
    func anyview() -> AnyView
}
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but `model` in `YTPlayer` is supposed to be an `@ObservedObject` (owned by something else) rather than a `@StateObject` (owned by the view)

Comment: It WAS the cause. That did it. Feel free to make it a would be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to `UIViewControllerRepresentable` with a custom `UIViewController` subclass that has `YTPlayerView` as its view to get access to `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear`.